# @font-face works on localhost but not online

Tags: css, google-chrome, cross-browser, font-face

i looked for a answer for my problem everywere, but nothing works...

My Font works locally on all browsers, but when i upload the website, the font works only in Firefox and IE?

This is my css:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'BebasNeueRegular';
    src: url('http://www.ist-immobilien.at/fonts/beba/bebasneue-webfont.eot');
    src: url('http://www.ist-immobilien.at/fonts/beba/bebasneue-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('eot'),
         url('http://www.ist-immobilien.at/fonts/beba/bebasneue-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('http://www.ist-immobilien.at/fonts/beba/bebasneue-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('http://www.ist-immobilien.at/fonts/beba/bebasneue-webfont.svg#webfontX0YNjQNl') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}
```

I have used relative urls too, but it didn't make a change. The Fonts are on the server.. i don't know, whats the problem..

The Siteurl is: [Site URL](http://www.ist-immobilien.at/wordpress/?p=1)
The blue Headers should be this font...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your CSS, you're actually looking for a font named `'BebasNeueRegular'` (with quotes in its name):

```
font-family: \'BebasNeueRegular\', sans-serif;
```

Remove those backslashes and it'll work.

Comment: Thank you, when i edit this on chrome developer tools, it works! 
But in my stylesheet there is no Backslash? Very strange, don't know why!

Comment: @ichx123: It's in your source code. Remove the quotes from your custom stylesheet.

Comment: I see it too, but this is a Options Panel of a Worpress theme, and there is no backslash. i update this code above!

Comment: @ichx123: Seems like a problem with the way your theme is written.

Comment: Okay, i will change this code in the stylesheet itself, i hope this helps. Thank you for finding the mistake itself ;)